# Is there a way for a tmux session to find out if it is itself a nested tmux session?

Tags: unix, tmux

If so, it will be possible to script keys which change which nested level of tmux handle the event based on context. e.g. I want a key to be handled by the host tmux if the nested inner tmux has only one pane open in its current window.

The host tmux can know that its current pane is running a tmux, which lets it "pass through" the key.

But now the child tmux, if its current window only has one pane, tell the *host* tmux "Oh thanks, I've only got one pane", so the host tmux can then carry on and do what it would normally do if its pane *wasn't running tmux*.

Now there's at least two ways: One is like I described, the host tmux always passes to the inner tmux. The problem here is I know not how the inner tmux can detect (1) that it is itself running in tmux, so it knows to report and (2) how to report to its host tmux any facts about its situation. For example my vimrc does this by calling out to `tmux` from within Vim (i.e. vimscript `system('tmux select-pane .+')`).

The other way is to somehow get the outer tmux to figure out which socket the inner tmux is, and call `tmux -S innertmux-socket` to deduce inner tmux's state, and based on that info determine whether to send in the command or not. There is no certainty to be had on the path of that socket based on its own tmux variables alone, but I think with some targeted shell scripting this won't be too hard.

Inception jokes welcome...

The question is serious though. This is no joke. Are there any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: this is old, but for others: tmux sets an environment variable called `$TMUX`, so you can use `if [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then TMUX_ONLY_CODE; fi`

Comment: this would not help determine whether the tmux session in which the command is executed is nested in another tmux session. Here are [some older and still relevant approaches](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/tmux-in-practice-local-and-nested-remote-tmux-sessions-4f7ba5db8795/).